# compile node which uses messages defined in an other machine

Tags: ros, communication, messages, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody
I have a problem. I am using INDIGO.
I am using as ROS MASTER my own account on my pc in communication with ROS running in a virtual machine.
The problem is that I would like to subscribe a message which is defined in the nodes belonging to the virtual machine and not to my catkin folder. So basically when I compile trying to include such message, I get a compilation error saying that this package is not found. (Obviously, because it is defined in the virtual machine).
Is there any workaround for that?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233827/compile-node-which-uses-messages-defined-in-an-other-machine/) by [jappoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26193/jappoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the reason why there are message-packages. If you have a package foo that contains a lot of algorithms, dependencies and message definitions, you should create a package foo-msgs that contains only the message-definitions.
The original foo package then depends on this foo-msgs. In your case, you'd then only have to install the foo-msgs package on your machine so set up the communication.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jappoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26193/jappoz/) on 2016-05-12**:
Thank you. So I did and it worked fine.